# Temporarily disable status update broadcasts on Chromecast receiver app?

Tags: google-cast

Our receiver will be supporting video advertisements and I was wondering if there's a way to temporarily disable the receiver from sending out the broadcasted status updates to all listening clients while an ad is playing.

For right now, our solution is to send out an "ad start" and an "ad end" message to let the clients handle ignoring any upcoming broadcasts, but it would be nice if we could disable them from being sent all-together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do that but one needs to extend RemoteMedia and override at least broadcastCurrentStatus() method there. It might be easier to do what you are currently doing.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the info. Will have to see if it's worth it :)

Comment: Now that the SDK is live, to explain the new way of doing this: mediaManager.customizedStatusCallback = function (mediaStatus) {
  // edit mediaStatus object and return it, or return null for no message
  return mediaStatus;
};